# Is my object copied memory or a pointer to the original object's memory?

Tags: c#, oop, memory-management

Sorry if the question seems weird, I didn't know how to really put this. Therefore, I'm not sure if this question has been asked before.

Take this piece of code:

```
    Object obj = new Object();

    Object obj2;

    obj2 = obj;
```

So my question is:

When I assign `obj` to `obj2`, is `obj2` pointing to `obj`'s memory, or is the runtime allocating a new chunk of memory that is identical to `obj`'s memory?

Thanks, Ro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj2` has a reference to the same object that `obj` points to. Since they are pointing to the same object, modifications to `obj2` are "reflected" in `obj`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example to illustrate that it is a reference and not a copy

```
 public class ClassObject
    {
        public int entier;

        public ClassObject(int p_Initial)
        {
            this.entier = p_Initial;
        }
    }



        ClassObject obj1 = new ClassObject(2);
        Console.WriteLine(obj1.entier); ==> Console obj1.entier = 2
        ClassObject obj2 = obj1;
        obj2.entier = 5;

        Console.WriteLine(obj1.entier); ==> Console obj1.entier = 5
        Console.WriteLine(obj2.entier); ==> Console obj2.entier = 5
```

Comment: If you want create a copy of an object in C# you can use an implementation of ICloneable Interface du namespace System.Object