# In C#, when I set a new list equal to another list, does it set the new list as a pointer to the other list or is it actually creating a new list?

Tags: c#, list, object, pointers

When I set a new list equal to another list, does it set the new list as a pointer to the other list or is it actually creating a new list?

For example,

Is...

```
List<SomeType> newList = oldList;
```

...the same as...

```
List<SomeType> newList = new List<SomeType>();
newList.AddRange(oldList);
```

(oldList is a list of SomeType as well)?

Comment: also it's quiete easy to figure it out experimentally...

Comment: Yes, but where would I find a list of all the datatypes that behave this way? I guess that's what I'm more interested in...

Comment: Almost all assignment in C# (or most languages really) are shallow. You're asking about a deep copy. Doing this by default would slow things down incredibly, and lead to some very unexpected behavior. (edit: yes there's the good ol' copy constructor in C++, and copy-by-value parameter passing, but let's not complicate this).

Comment: My precedent answer of this subject

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18625553/is-my-object-copied-memory-or-a-pointer-to-the-original-objects-memory/18625657#18625657

Comment: @Alexandru All reference types behave this way.  The assignment operator copies all value types (and their respective values, recursively, but references contained within the value type are copied, not the referenced obejct).

Comment: To be honest, I asked this question because I thought it might help others in the future, but I'd be appalled if I were new to Stack and got such responses from some of you. Down-voting your peers and all, come on guys...

Comment: @Alexandru If you ask quality questions that follow the site's guidelines you won't get downvotes.  Being a new user doesn't make you immune to those standards.  Having them is what separates this site for so many others, and is why it generally has so much higher quality content.  If you improve the question you may find it will get more upvotes than downvotes going forward.

Comment: @Servy Keep in mind that I've been a member longer than you, friend. I tried phrasing my question in such a way that someone new to C# might ask it so that when someone web searches this topic they find the posting sufficient to their needs.

Comment: @Alexandru How long you have been a user is irrelevant.  The quality of the question is.  This is not a quality question.  There are a few thousand duplicate questions or other resources on the topic out there on the web.  One more isn't helpful.

Comment: @Servy I wasn't aware someone put you in charge of quality control. I think, conceptually, our views on what "quality questions are", "what's helpful for others", and "what's good for long-run of this site" interfere. Perhaps you should stick to commenting on questions that meet your quality standards. Thanks ;)

Comment: @Alexandru The community is responsible for managing the quality of content on the site.  People manage it through votes.  They downvote content that is of low quality.  You seems to have trouble understanding why you were being downvoted, so I spent some of my time helping you out by explaining both some of the problems with your post that you can fix, and also why the current system is so important, since you seem to not agree with it or understand it.  It's an important process on this site to help improve content not of superb quality, hence the comment feature in the first place.

Comment: @Servy You misunderstand my point. My point is that I'd wish for you to concentrate your efforts on answering questions rather than posting opinionated comments. Your opinions do not represent the whole general public's, for if they did, people would not have posted answers to this question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There will be one `List` and multiple references to it. This applies for all reference types (classes).

Value types (structs), on the other hand, are copied when assigned.

Comment: Theodoros, where would I find a list of all the built-in reference types in C#? Edit: Perhaps, its better to just find a list of all the value types in C# since its smaller, and consider all other types reference types then?

Comment: @Alexandru To determine it programmatically, there is `Type.IsStruct`. To determine it while writing code, look for hints in your IDE (for example, VS has a different IntelliSense icon for structs, as far as I remember). If this is not possible for any reason, then check the documentation of the library you're using at that point.

Comment: Great answer, man. Thanks for respecting the question and going in-depth on the subject.

Answer (score 5):

The assignment operator is **not** a cloning operator. In case of reference types, it copies values of references.

Answer (score 4):

In assignement like:

```
List<SomeType> newList = oldList;
```

Both list will be exactly the same, adding or removing one item in a list will make it change in the other list. They both use the same memory space beside an extra pointer.

```
List<SomeType> newList = new List<SomeType>();
newList.AddRange(oldList);
```

Will be 2 separates independant list (both in memory). Change in one list will not affect the other one.

Keep in mind, if your "SomeType" is a complex type... lets say a "product". In BOTH CASE, all list will be reference to your products, so a change in a product will be changed in the other list.

To make the list copied AND the product you need to clone the product and that can be tricking because cloning is recursive depending on the complexity of the type.